# Transaction Log Rate

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We are considering to move over production databases to Azure SQL Database. While reading the article the point [Transaction Log Rate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-resource-limits-database-server#transaction-log-rate-governance) flashes a red light. Our databases are not designed very well, lots of `NVARCHAR(MAX)` columns, stores a large volume of JSON document etc.

According to Microsoft document

> These limits are tracked and enforced at the sub-second level to the
>   rate of log record generation, limiting throughput regardless of how
>   many IOs may be issued against data files.

Before migrating the databases to Azure, I would like to evaluate our on-premises databases to see whether it would become a victim of throttling.

How can I do it?

Comment: [`sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats` is your friend](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/11/sql-performance/transaction-log-monitoring). Azure is documented to have a rate limit of 96 MB/sec; you can check on your production database if you're getting anywhere near that. Note that typical analysis focuses on the *latency* of transaction writes, as that is the practical bottleneck in most production setups; this is obviously correlated to the amount of data written per second, but not necessarily in a simple linear fashion. For Azure your task would be simpler, as it's a limit on the total data.

Comment: Thanks. What about Database Log byte flushed counter?

Comment: That works equally well. You can access the perf counters from T-SQL as well (`sys.dm_os_performance_counters`), but they're a little harder to use correctly than the IO views in terms of proper sampling and decoding the counter type. (Or you can just use Performance Monitor, of course.)

Comment: Thanks. Are there any other limitation, I remember reading some article a couple of years back that said if a query executes more than x minutes or use x resource then it gets disconnected.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that as long as you don't exceed your pool CPU/IO resources (and set command timeouts appropriately) your queries could run for as long as the resources last, and there's no fixed runtime limit, but I have no personal experience with Azure. (Even if there was a fixed runtime limit, it would be hard to say what the impact was on the running time of your existing queries when moving to Azure.)